# PHP declaring variables

Tags: php

Looking for advice on how to do this properly.  Recently upgraded from php 7 to 8.

I have never declared any variables before in php but now php8 isn't happy with me trying to conduct math operations on variables it knows to be strings.

For example, my old php7 code looks something like this

```
$minutes = $_POST['minutes'];
$time = $time + $minutes;
```

But in php8, it doesn't like this, I have add to make the following modification (in many places to get it working)

```
$minutes = $_POST['minutes'];
$time = $time + (int)$minutes;
```

My question is, is the correct way to do this now going forward or is there a better way to do this once with maybe a general declaration somewhere?

Comment: Do the conversion when you set the variable, so you don't have to repeat it everywher e you use it: `$minutes = intval($_POST['minutes']);`

Comment: I don't see anything in the list of incompatible changes in PHP 8 that would require this. There's a change to the way *comparisons* work between strings and numbers, but nothing about arithmetic. What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: @Barmar reproduced here ~ https://3v4l.org/F1a7u

Comment: @Phil That only happens when the string is not a valid number. Use `$minutes = $_POST['minutes'] ?? "5";` and it works fine.

Comment: Basically, they removed non-numeric strings implicitly converting to `0`.

Comment: @Barmar I'm aware but you asked for details regarding the error. OP, check out [filter_input()](https://www.php.net/manual/function.filter-input.php) for a generally better way to handle input validation

Comment: True. But I was assuming that the string was a number that could be validly added to `$time`. If it's not, the original code is wrong and using `(int)` just hides the problem. They might as well use `@` to suppress the error.

Comment: BTW, just `$a = $b` does declare a variable. You’ve been doing that a lot probably.

Comment: @deceze how are we closing this one?  Do we want debugging details? Is it opinion-based? Shall we steer them to a dupe target?

Comment: I guess someone should mention `$time += $minutes;`

Comment: You should always validate user input before using it.

Comment: Some other languages allow to declare variables (for example, in C you can do `int time;`) but PHP doesn't, there's not even a syntax for that. Variables are automatically declared the first time you write into them. What PHP complaints about is when you **read** from a variable that you never wrote. Surely, it already did in PHP/7 but you didn't configure PHP to display notices, but your new PHP/8 installation is configured to do so.

Comment: Said that, I think this question is wrong. If it gets fixed by casting to int, then you're getting a different error.